# Should deep learning classification be used to classify details such as liquid level in bottle

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

Can `deep learning classification` be used to precisely `label/classify` both the object and one of its features. For example to identify the bottle *(like Grants Whiskey)* and liquid level in the bottle *(in 10 percent steps - like 50% full)*. Is this the problem that can be best solved utilizing some of `deep learning frameworks` *(Tensorflow etc)* or some other approach is more effective?

Comment: You should be asking "SHOULD deep learning classification be used to...". Nowadays it seems that every CV problem must be solved using deep learning, people forget that they should not overkill problems.

Comment: I agree Pedro - that is why I asked should if deep learning should be used or some other approach in the body of the question. I will try to change the question title now as well.

Comment: The thing is, to have deep learning taking care of that task you must collect tens of thousands of labelled pics with different content levels to have it learn. I think you should try some simple gradient approach proposed in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this should be well possible if the liquor is well colored. If not (e.g. gin, vodka), I'd say you have no chance with today's technologies when observing the object from a natural view angle and distance.

For colored liquor, I'd train two detectors. One for detecting the bottle, and a second one to detect the liquor given the bottle. The ratio between the two will be your percentage.

Some of the proven state-of-the-art deep learning-based object detectors (just Google them):

- Multibox
- YOLO
- Faster RCNN

Or non-deep-learning-based:

- Deformable part model

EDIT:

I was ask to elaborate more. Here is an example:

The box detector e.g. draws a box in the image at [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6] (min_height, min_width, max_height, max_width) which is the relative location of your bottle.

Now you crop the bottle from the original image and feed it to the second detector. The second detector draws e.g. [0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8] in your cropped bottle image, the location indicates the fluid it has detected. Now (0.7 - 0.2) * (0.8 - 0.3) = 0.25 is the relative area of the fluid with respect to the area of the bottle, which is what OP is asking for.

EDIT 2:

I entered this reply assuming OP wants to use deep learning. I'd agree other methods should be considered if OP is still unsure with deep learning. For bottle detection, deep learning-based methods have shown to outperform traditional methods by a large margin. Bottle detection happens to be one of the classes in the PASCAL VOC challenge. See results comparison here: http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/detection_datasets_results.html#50617363616c20564f43203230313020636f6d7034

For the liquid detection however, deep learning might be slightly overkill. E.g. if you know what color you are looking for, even a simple color filter will give you "something"....

Comment: `The ratio between the two will be your percentage` how can you identify the percentage of the liquor in the bottle? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Added an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb for deep learning is, if it is visible in the image, hence a expert can tell you the answer solely based on the image then the chances are very high that you can learn this with deep learning, given enough annotated data.

However you are quite unlikely to have the required data needed for such a task, therefore I would ask myself the question if i can simplify the problem. For example you could take gin, vodka and so on and use SIFT to find the bottle again in a new scene. Then RANSAC for bottle detection and cut the bottle out of the image.

Then I would try gradient features to find the edge with the liquid level. Finally you can calculate the percentage with (liquid edge - bottom) / (top bottle - bottom bottle).

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the bottle label should not be hard to do - it's even available "on tap" for cheap ([these guys](https://www.baacco.com/) actually use it to identify wine bottle labels on their website): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rekognition-image-detection-and-recognition-powered-by-deep-learning/

Regarding the liquid level, this might be a problem AWS wouldn't be able to solve straight away - but I'm sure it's possible to make a custom CNN for it. Alternatively, you could use good old humans on Amazon Mechanical Turk to do the work for you.

(Note: I do not work for Amazon)